# Is there a way to build cpputest with pthreads disabled?

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, arm, cpputest, eabi

I'm planning to use cpputest as a testing framework in my project which I need to cross compile as it will be used on ARM platform. The compiler I'm using for ARM development is arm-gcc which is built with pthreads disabled. Due to this, I need to build cpputest without pthreads. Currently l am following the autotool approach for building cpputest. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compile, download, and run CppUTest on a target device?

Typically, CppUTest isn't compiled and downloaded to your target device but instead it's built as a Windows (or Linux) console application.  This means that CppUTest gets compiled using a native compiler (Visual Studio or GCC) but your firmware will also need to compile using that same native compiler (Visual Studio or GCC).

Unit testing is meant to verify that your code's logic is correct, which means it doesn't matter if the code is executing on an ARM processor or in an Intel processor.  For the record, when I first started getting into unit testing this blew my mind.

But what about hardware registers and stuff like that?  Well, there's ways around testing embedded devices hardware in a Windows environment.  At the end of the day, you'll still need to download your firmware onto the embedded device and verify that your port mappings are correct (i.e. That you're properly settings up a GPIO port to turn on an LED for instance).

There's several advantages to running your unit testing on your development PC instead of on target.  Your development PC is much faster, has more resources (i.e. storage and RAM) and it also easily allows for running in a continuous integration environment (like Jenkins or TeamCity) whenever you check-in code to your version control system.

I highly recommend the book [Test-Driven Development for Embedded C by James W. Grenning](https://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c) for more information.  It will answer all your questions on unit testing on an embedded device.  CppUTest can be used for C as well as C++ projects.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I was somehow under the impression that the tests should run on actual target as that's where its supposed to work. But what you mentioned makes sense as its more about verifying the logic.